# Implications of Fulltext Search over many columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a really wide table which includes separate columns for billing address, shipping address, primary address, names, aliases etc. (I can't normalize this table further, and that's not the question here anyways).

I'm implementing SQL Server fulltext search, and I'm wondering whether I should limit the search ability to just the primary fields (primary address and names for example), or if I can extend the search ability across all columns without occurring too much of a performance or memory penalty.

I've done some basic testing with 10,000 sample rows and it's quite fast but I don't have much experience with fulltext indexing, especially its dictionary internals, so I don't know if the index is going to grow over time, or if there is anything else to consider.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

See 2008 Books Online ***Getting Started with Full-Text Search*** for some considerations.